# What document describes the scientific benefits of the LRV through an increase in the diversity of rocks returned by Apollo 15-17?

Tags: apollo-program, planetary-science, lunar-rover

Logically, it makes sense that the rock samples returned by the Apollo 15-17 missions tend to be more diverse than the ones returned by previous missions. The astronauts could reach regions of interest far away from the lunar module thanks to the lunar roving vehicle (LRV). Lots of reports, such as [this LEAG white paper](https://www.lpi.usra.edu/leag/reports/HumanExplorationDecadalWhitePaper_Final.pdf) (section 2.3) and [this 2019 paper](https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1029/2018EA000490) (section 3.5), make this argument.

Most papers discussing the scientific benefits of the LRV either stick to this logical argument, or only point out the *quantity* of rocks returned by Apollo 15-17. In my opinion, a more convincing metric would be the *diversity* of the samples returned.

My question: **Are there publicly-available papers/reports describing the scientific benefits of the LRV by quantifying the *diversity* of samples returned by Apollo 15-17?**

Comment: Definitive comparison would possibly need to include other factors such as varying diversity at different landing locations, as well as the astronaut training. On one extreme was Apollo 17 with geologist Jack Schmitt. On the other was Apollo 14, which probably should be counted in your survey since they had the MET (Modular Equipment Transporter), a two-wheeled cart for carrying tools and samples, allowing them to travel nearly a mile from the LM. But scientists were disappointed in the geology work that the Apollo 14 astronauts did at what was considered a very important geologic site.

Comment: It's difficult to predict diversity of geological samples, it partly depends on the quality of the people investigating a site: recognizing what's there & taking appropriate samples, as @StevePemberton mentions about Apollo 14. Then there are serendipitous moments such as when "orange soil" was discovered & sampled during the Apollo 17 mission.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Indeed, there are a lot of factors that come into play when discussing the "diversity" of samples returned by each Apollo mission. Perhaps the best proof would be in the return on science that each mission had over the years. For instance, given the extent of terrain covered by Apollo 15-17 with the LRV, I would expect a better overall understanding about the geologic history of the sites they landed in compared with those visited by Apollo 11,12 (and perhaps 14).